# CookieManager function of dio_cookie_manager plugin conflict with flutter_inappwebview Cookiemanager

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, dio, cookiemanager

When I use the CookieManager function of dio_cookie_manager plugin into the page of included flutter_inappwebview plugin, I got the errors:

> The argument type 'CookieManager' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'interceptors'

and

> 'CookieManager' isn't a function.

How can I use both plugins with separate Cookiemanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid such conflicts, make sure that you use `import '...' as customName`.
For example;

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/cookie_manager.dart' as dioCookieManager;
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
```

in that case, you can use it like

```
var dio =  Dio();
  var cookieJar = CookieJar();
  dio.interceptors.add(dioCookieManager.CookieManager(cookieJar));
// ...
```

so you can avoid conflicts with other packages as well.